# NewLine escape character not working

Tags: javascript, html, newline

We know that \n is used to feed a new line in JavaScript.
How should I use it for an output (in a for-loop):

```
str=prompt("Enter any string!");
    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        document.write('\n'+str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
```

or

```
str=prompt("Enter any string!");
    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        document.write('\n'+str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
```

Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JavaScript. In HTML, all whitespace (including newlines) is collapsed and treated as a single space.

To do a line break in HTML:

- Use [`<br>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-br-element.html#the-br-element)
- Or organize your text into paragraphs with [`<p>...</p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-p-element.html#the-p-element), etc.)
- Or if you're outputting some form of formatted text (like code), you can do that in a [`<pre>...</pre>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-pre-element.html#the-pre-element) element (or any element with the [`white-space: pre`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-white-space), `white-space: pre-wrap`, or `white-space: pre-line` style applied to it).

Comment: I see, what for is \n then? Is it ever used as I did?

Comment: @popstack: JavaScript is not limited to dealing with HTML; it's a general-purpose language. (Originally not even designed for web browsers, but rather for a web *server*; but it was then quickly added to Netscape Navigator and the rest is history.) When dealing with other things, `\n` may be a line break. For instance, even in browsers, `alert("Foo\nbar");` shows two lines in the alert box, because the text you give to `alert` isn't HTML.

Comment: Agreed. You may want your source code to be printed cleanly. Even when displaying HTML, viewing the source will treat white space differently than HTML outputs to the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing to the document you'll want `document.write('<br/>'+str.charCodeAt(i));`
- or to set your output in a `<pre>` tag (or another element with the a style attribute of `white-space:pre`).

Comment: @popstack: `<br/>` is the XHTML version of `<br>`. Since you're not using XHTML, you would just use `<br>`. (How do I know you're not using XHTML? Because you're using `document.write`, which you can't use in XHTML.)

Comment: you can use either - the self closing `<br/>` is valid for all doctypes whereas `<br>` would be invalid for an XHTML doctype

Comment: @ Mikey: *Grr, strikethrough doesn't work in comments. Pretend you see strikethrough as indicated.* <s>`<br/>` isn't valid in HTML4 and earlier. Browsers tolerate it, but it's wrong. In HTML5, there's a special parsing case specifically to allow it (because people kept using it incorrectly in HTML documents).</s> I may have to take that back, I just tried the validator telling it to use HTML 4.01 strict, and it let it through. Could have *sworn* it wasn't valid.

Comment: And, should I use single quotes or double? Do we have guidelines on that (I have to use HTML 4.01 strict)?

Comment: javascript will accept either `"` or `'` so long as you use the same quote at each end of the string

Answer (score 1):

I made a much better solution. See it in action https://repl.it/@mamamia5x/Example

In css do

```
h1 span::before { 
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Replace the h1 with whatever you have. Now, whenever you do `<span>`, a new line will break. So whenever someone says /n, it'll do the `<span>` and make a new line.

```
if (txt.charAt(i) == '/' && txt.charAt(i + 1) =='n'){
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += " <span>";
   i = i + 2;
}
```

Here is it in action https://repl.it/@mamamia5x/Example, and here is a project I am using it for https://live-stream.mamamia5x.repl.co/.

I also made it work with `<br>`. If you want to do that, you can do

```
if (txt.charAt(i) == '<' && txt.charAt(i + 1) == 'b' && txt.charAt(i + 2) == 'r' && txt.charAt(i + 3) == '>'){
```

You can also mix the two together, and it can allow `/n` and `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

use document.writeln() method .

The writeln() method is identical to the write() method, with the addition of writing a newline character after each statement.

try this

```
 str=prompt("Enter any string!");
 for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
 {
    document.writeln(str.charCodeAt(i));
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

use **`<br>`**  instead of **\n**
it relative to HTML