# New line is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

New line is not working in Javascript.

I am using new to add two string and second string should be in new line but `\n` is not working.

My code is like

```
var s1 = "Hello";
var s2 = " My world";

var s3 = s1 +"\n"+ s2
```

output shuld be like :

Hello

**My** World

any suggetion. thanks for help

Comment: it's working no problem , remove space in s2

Comment: Output *where* ? In HTML ? Then a newline isn't rendered as a new line but that's an HTML question. In a console ? Then it's console dependent.

Comment: I am using this in Javascript

Comment: Please make a fiddle demonstrating your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: change your title to bold is not working in javascript

Comment: You can find the solution to this problem by checking [this link here][1].
[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225878/newline-escape-character-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<b></b>` to add the bold and `<br>` for the line break

```js
var s1 = "Hello";
var s2 = "<b>My</b> world";

var s3 = s1 + "<br>" + s2;

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = s3;
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: How to make "My" as a bold character

Comment: @David Where should be the output ?

Comment: On screen as a tool tip

Comment: @David Thus in HTML ?

Comment: I have to write html code in my js file ?

Comment: or use `s2.split(" ")[0].toString().bold()`