# Html not rendering javascript breaklines as intended

Tags: javascript, html

I have a json file which contains some texts, and some of these texts could have some breaklines

```
"surchargeNoteText":"Please note \r \n that pre-payments will take up to 2 business \r \n days to be allocated to your reservation",
```

I tried to use \r and/or \n and the result was this
[image]

So, the funny thing is that when inspecting the html, the output is right, with 2 break lines.

[image]

So, any tips here ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this. Please refer below given link [NewLine escape character not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225878/newline-escape-character-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<pre>` tag to keep the text formatted as you wish

```html
<pre>
I am inside
   a pre
          Tag!
<pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below **CSS** will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
p.jss98 {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Html you need to add `<br />` to break lines.

`"surchargeNoteText":"Please note <br /> that pre-payments will take up to 2 business <br /> days to be allocated to your reservation",`

Comment: its not html, this text is coming from a json file

Comment: No problem. Then use

`let surchargeNoteText = surchargeNoteText.replace('\r \n', '<br />');`

Comment: its actually rendering <br /> as a string, not interpretating as a html tag

Comment: I guess this is because the value is injected in the HTML document using [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) instead of [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (before using the latter, make sure to read "Security considerations").

Answer (score 0):

Use `&nbsp;` instead of `\r` and `<br/>` instead of `\n`. In HTML, `\r` and `\n` doesn't works.

Comment: its not html. its a dynamic text which comes from a json file

Comment: @vbotio HTML doesn't render these tags you are getting from JSON. You can replace them in JS before appending it in HTML.